# Sorty by array field PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

my array looks like this:

```
array(3) { 
[1]=> array(2) { 
    ["username"]=> string(8) "bob123" 
    ["percent"]=> int(100) 
} 
[2]=> array(2) { 
    ["username"]=> string(13) "bryan123" 
    ["percent"]=> int(0) 
} 
[3]=> array(2) { 
    ["username"]=> string(8) "jim123" 
    ["percent"]=> int(0) 
} 
}
```

I would like to sort by the percent field inside of my array titled $friends, how would I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array

```
$array = array(
  array("username"=> "bob123", "percent"=> 10),
  array("username"=> "bob123", "percent"=> 9),
  array("username"=> "bob123", "percent"=> 9)
  );
```

Function callback for usort

```
function callb($a, $b){
  if($a['percent'] == $b['percent']){
    return 0;
  }
  return ($a['percent'] > $b['percent'])? +1:-1;  
}
```

Usage

```
usort($array,"callb");
 print_r($array);
```

https://eval.in/85986

Comment: This is pretty dang close!  However if there are two entries with the same percent one is deleted!  Any ideas on that?

Comment: Ya that's a problem there. I will check it now

Comment: @user3162154 update the answer with usort. Try now

Answer (score 3):

Write a comparison function that comapares two elements according to your preferred order and pass that function along with the array to [`usort`](http://de3.php.net/usort).